# D3 - Using color from JSON for chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a JSON file which looks like this:

```
{  
   "name":"TOPICS",
   "children":[  
      {  
         "name":"Topic A",
         "children":[  
            {  
               "name":"Anna",
               "size":5,
               "text":"A story",
               "sentiment":0.8,
               "source":"dictionary",
               "color":"gray"
            },
```

This is fed into a D3 chart which reads this file. What I am trying to do is like the existing fill function below:

```
.style("fill", function (d) { return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).data.name); });
```

To instead pull the colour from the json. In this case, gray. Can anyone please help me?

EDIT: Based on the help below I have this code but it still does not work:

```
g.selectAll('g')
    .data(root.descendants())
    .enter().append('g').attr("class", "node").append('path')
    .attr("display", function (d) { return d.depth ? null : "none"; })
    .attr("d", arc)
    .style('stroke', '#fff')
    .style("fill", d => (d.children? d: d.parent).data.color);

// Populate the <text> elements with our data-driven titles.
g.selectAll(".node")
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")rotate(" + computeTextRotation(d) + ")"; })
    .attr("dx", "-20") // radius margin
    .attr("dy", ".5em") // rotation align
    .text(function(d) { return d.parent ? d.data.name : "" });

});
```

Comment: `.data.name` ====>>>> `.data.color`

Comment: @rioV8 I did try that but had no luck :(

Comment: Did you also remove the `color(...)` function wrapper? In the end, it should be as simple as `.style("fill", d => (d.children? d: d.parent).data.color);`

Comment: @SteveR I've posted how my code looks now. It makes the background black entirely, and does not seem to pull through when I inspect element.

Comment: Then the data coming into the function is not what you expect... but since you don't show us what the output of the `root.descendants()` function looks, I'm just guessing.

Comment: @SteveR Managed to get it working with this code, but not even sure why ```  .style("fill", function (d) { return d.parent ? d.data.color: "gray" });```

Comment: do a `console.log(d)` that is such a nice tool, I wish every javascript programmer knew about it, or read about it.